# System Generator configuration for Xilinx Co Simulation

Tags: simulink, xilinx, system-generator

I'm working on a cosimulation in simulink using either 2012a or 2011b, and System Generator 13.1.  When building the library block for the hardware to be loaded onto the zynq fpga, I configure the system generator to be a 'Hardware Co-Sim,' everything through this step works. However, in the simulink/pc end of the simulation, I haven't found any good resources for how to configure.  **Am I correct in assuming it also should be set as a hardware co-sim and not some other setup (HDL netlist) or anything like that?**

Currently, the system seems to be loading the block just fine, but the jtag library is missing, not sure if this is a sysgen issue, or software versioning issue.  My understanding is that sysgen is still in beta for 2012a.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question will be answered faster if you post it on Xilinx forum : http://forums.xilinx.com

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be set as a hardware co-simulation (Your board->connection type).
Configuring of board occurs when You start simulation. (Or You can program it manually using Impact and next check "skip configuration" in block properties).